# Spring 5 - custom qualifiers for @Bean methods - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I've been struggling a while now with using custom @Qualifier in conjunction with @Bean over the factory method. It looks like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE, 
ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface MyCustomQualifierUno {
    String value() default "";
}

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE, 
ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface MyCustomQualifierDos {
    String value() default "";
}
```

And the factory class for desired beans consists of the below two methods:

```
@Bean
@MyCustomQualifierUno
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(SomeConfigUno config,
    SomeErrorHandlerUno errorHandler) {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            (...)
            .build();
}

@Bean
@MyCustomQualifierDos
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(SomeConfigDos config,
    SomeErrorHandlerDos errorHandler) {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            (...)
            .build();
}
```

Next, in the Client class I have a ctor injection done like this:

```
public SomeClientUno(@SomeQualifierUno RestTemplate 
    restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}

public SomeClientDos(@SomeQualifierDos RestTemplate 
    restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
```

When I'm trying to run the app I get:
[NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugDvL.png)

Quite intriguing tough is the fact, that when I add a dedicated class that extends the RestTemplate and placed there my @CustomQualifier I get exception, that there are actually two beans now (i.e. now it does consider the @Bean method)!

Running through: IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.1
OS: Windows 10 64bit
Java: 1.8.0_191
Spring version: 5.1.9

PS. Those "Uno's and 'Dos'ses are meant to stress the fact, that those are some concrete types, quite irrelevant, but don't get confused with the "Uno's and 'Dos'ses in the @Qualifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem too obvious, but why should you use Qualifiers at all?
Let's assume you define your beans like this:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplateUno(...) { ... }

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplateDos(...) { ... }
```

This registers the beans with the qualifiers "restTemplateUno" and "restTemplateDos", because "By default, the bean name will be the same as the method name" (see [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html) for details).

You could now inject them in the client constructors like this:

```
@Autowired
public SomeClientUno(RestTemplate restTemplateUno) {...}

@Autowired
public SomeClientDos(RestTemplate restTemplateDos) {...}
```

I hope this helps and I didn't miss something obvious that caused you to consider using Qualifiers in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that was it (method naming)! The exception from Spring is quite misleading IMO though...

Comment: Agreed, takes some time getting used to that. Would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks.